# how to enable secure boot after the installation

Tags: kubuntu, windows-8, uefi, grub-efi

- Kubuntu 14.04 64bit on a MS-DOS (MBR) type HDD (sd**a**4)
- Kubuntu 14.10 64bit on a GPT type HDD (sd**b**5)
- Windows 8.1 64bit on a GPT type HDD (sd**a**3)

these are my installed OSes, both *kubuntu* installations were made with "*secure boot* **off**" state. Now I need to turn *secure boot* **ON**. but enabling secure mode ignores the *grub* and head to windows 8. also it indicates an *error* with the boot saying "**invalid signature detected**..."

do I need to add *grub-efi* signature to efi-firmware? or how can I enable secure boot correctly?

---

> motherboard intel DH77KC

Comment: secure boot and uefi are two different things, at least in my bios. These settings are enabled/disabled in your bios. As far as I know, with uefi, you need to install with uefi enabled (I do not know a way to convert post install). Generally you then select which OS to boot in your bios . Most of this is covered in http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported , see the troubleshooting section.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks for your comment. yes secure boot and efi (or uefi) are two things (actually secure boot is a feature of efi which keeps windows secure) and I can also turn off secure boot and efi mode (secure boot depends on efi mode) in my bios. also it is possible to convert a regular linux installation to a efi capable installation :)

Comment: there is no problem with efi-grub.... grub is installed as efi capable and system boots up with efi mode (CSM diasbled)...and I can use both kubuntu OSes and Windows 8.1 ...problem occurs when I trun on the secure boot option, I don't know where is the error...bios os the efi-grub...visual bios says signature error and it leads to windows straight without displaying the grub :(

Comment: If it boots to windows without displaying grub, try looking at your bios and select which OS to boot from the bios. Most of this is covered in http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported , see the troubleshooting section.

Comment: From the link I gave you ..."TROUBLESHOOT

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP
" read on ...